# Integer representation of rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a $n\times m$ rectangular matrix A over a field $k$, does there exist a $m\times q $ matrix $Q$ such that $QQ^T=I$ and $AQ$ has only integer elements.

This does not hold in general. A simple counterexample is the matrix
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

If we consider a $2\times n$ matrix $Q$
\begin{equation}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&... & a_n\\b_1&b_2 & ... & b_n\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
then we have
\begin{equation}
AQ=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2&... & a_n\\b_1/2&b_2/2 & ... & b_n/2\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
For $AQ$ to have integer elements we must have that $b_i\geq2$, but this is not compatible with the constraint that $QQ^T=I$.

So my question is when is such a representation possible? Are there any meaningful criteria?